# How do I access the object inside this function?

Tags: javascript

I want to access the properties of the car object inside this function?

```
       function initStage(){ 
       var cars = {
       car: "ford", speed: 300
       } }
```

Comment: You can't access that object outside the function unless you make it accessible.

Comment: You can return the object.

Comment: Wait a second - *inside the function*? `cars.<prop>`...

Comment: *"properties of the car object"*? Did you mean *"properties of the **cars** object"*?

Answer (score 2):

You can't access it from outside the function the way you've written it, that would be accessing it out of the scope the function defines.

You could define the variable `cars` outside the function and then set it inside the function. Then, once the function was called, you could access the values set by it.

```
var cars;

function initStage(){ 
    cars = {
        car: "ford",
        speed: 300
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The scope of that object is the function that it is declared in.

However you can return the value.

```
function initStage(){ 
   var cars = {
     car: "ford", speed: 300
   } 
   return cars;
}

var initCars = initStage();
```

Depending on ur requirements, You could also make it a constructor and have the cars object a property of the instance.

```
function initStage(){ 
  this.cars = {
    car: "ford", speed: 300
  } 
}

new initStage().cars
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access it directly

```
  function initStage(){ 
       var cars = {
       car: "ford", speed: 300
       } 
      console.log(cars.car);
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

Four possible solutions:

**Return the value of the object**

```
function getCar(){
    var cars = {
           car: "ford", speed: 300
       }
    return cars
}
```

So that you can use getCar() to get the cars object

```
getCar() // {car:"ford",speed:300}
```

**Define the object with your function (Constructor Notation)**

```
function car(car,speed){
    this.car = car
    this.speed = speed
}
```

Then you can define a new car like this:

```
ford = new car("Ford",200)
ford //{car:"Ford",speed:200}
```

**Define the object with your function (Literal Notation)**

```
var cars; //Define cars for later access
function setCar(){
    cars = {
           car: "ford", speed: 300
       }
}
```

And then you can use the variable cars to get the cars object

```
cars // {car:"ford",speed:300}
```

**Get rid of the functions and just use literal notation**

```
var cars = {
   car: "ford", speed: 300
   }
```

Which you can then access with

```
cars //{car:"ford",speed:300}
```

All of these are viable options, allowing many ways to achieve the same task. I recommend the last as it is the most simple.